# alternative to firefox (firebug) for developers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug

Hi I am big fan of firebug and firefox. Cant imagine development without them. But the problem is end of the day firefox heaps up to 1GB of ram. I wish to see if there is an alternative. I know chrome exists but I didnt find it so comfortable. 

 

 
Is it (chrome) really worth to learn from scratch 
P.S. If there exists a Question already , Please direct me there. Alternative to firefox !!

Comment: FWIW (a) Personally I find the developer tools in Webkit much more comfortable (so this is subjective) and (b) they are working on [reducing the memory usage](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Firefox-developers-locate-a-source-of-bloat-1273916.html).

Comment: Am not surebut May This help You
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench and 
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: @Felix
oh thats good news . Thanks for the update . 
And webkit is worth trying is it ? . .
Thankyou !!

Comment: @Pratik
Thanks a lot !! I will try that and let you know !!!

Comment: @pratik 
Thats a good news !! But its very very early stages I guess. We need to wait !

Comment: @Skeptor: Uhm, I just referred to Webkit because both Chrome and Safari use Webkit and they use the same developer tools. It was probably wrong to connect these.

Comment: Ok,Thanx Skeptor,We have to wait..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome's developer tools is almost as good as Firebug, in fact Safari has the same Developer Tools (Apple developed those tools which Chrome incorporated). Firebug is definitely superior. The errors it reports are more verbose and accurate, and it seems to be a little better suited to dealing with certain things, like response from $.ajax() and more. Chrome can show you the response and the parameters sent and what not, but Firebug is just structure in a more logical, user-friendly way.

At the end of the day, for most web development tasks, Chrome Developer Tools is suited, and the CSS inspector is almost as good as Firebug's but for large scale projects I still revert to Firebug when I am stuck.

Comment: Also there is not much to learn if you already know how to use Firebug.

Comment: may be I should spend more time on it. I find the javascript debugging not so user-friendly . 
Thanks , I will give it a try

Comment: The XHR request will be shown after the result is arrived, sometimes I dont know if the request started or not. How to find it in chrome ?

Comment: UPDATE : It appears in 'others' !! :)

Comment: In the Console tab of Chrome, right click in a blank space and select 'XMLHttpRequest Logging'. It is not as good as firebug, but you can still click on the request to get details about the request (parameters sent, response etc...)